# robotic arm not working with pyserial and gcode

Tags: pyserial

I am working on a robotic arm.
M106 is turn on the fan 
M17 is stepper on
M18 is stepper off
G1 X... Y.. X.. is the coordinates of movement

the port is correct, the terminal prints the `hello   hi` there...
However the robotic arm is not moving, I totally have no clue why is this happening.
Is it there is some problem with my code?

```
import serial
import struct

def gcode_encode(gcode):
    gcode += '\r\n'
    return struct.pack(f'<{len(gcode)}s', gcode.encode(encoding='utf-8'))


print("hello")
# ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM7'
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.timeout = 0
ser.open()

g = gcode_encode('M106')
ser.write(b'g')

g = gcode_encode('M17')
ser.write(b'g')

g = gcode_encode('M18')
ser.write(b'g')

g = gcode_encode('G1 X0 Y120 Z120')
ser.write(b'g')

g = gcode_encode('G1 X50 Y120 Z60')
ser.write(b'g')

ser.close()

print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing only the character 'g' to the port. If you want to write bytes of a variable `g`, you need to use `bytes(g)`. The same is with `f'<{len(gcode)}s'`, the characters in single or double quotes are not a command here, but just a string. Also you don't need packing of the string, just encoding.

Also add some pauses between commands using `time.sleep()`.